# Eloquent (without Laravel) caching implementation

Tags: php, caching, eloquent

I am using Eloquent without Laravel and I'm wondering if there's a method which can be used (and does not rely on Laravel components) to integrate a caching method which then automatically caches all model queries (caching backend can be variable, say APCu or memcache).

I'm thinking that it should be possible to write a model base class which handles this but I'm not quite sure how I would go about implementing this. Does anybody have any ideas in this direction?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://www.edzynda.com/use-laravels-eloquent-orm-outside-of-laravel/

Comment: Cool link, I just wish the author would show and example of how to implement this caching layer rather than plugging his book. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to auto cache your query, you have to override the find(), findOrFail() , where() ... methods

Because of how Eloquent is built you can't simply add a method find() in your custom model class

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/override-find-method/replies/72028

```
class MyCacheModel extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
// override methods as explained in previous link
// cache the result in redis for how long you want
}
```

Then in your model instead of extending Eloquent\Model, extends now from your MyCacheModel. With a bit of customization you can set how long queries will be cached and if a model shouldn't be cached then just use the Eloquent\Model.

Comment: I was afraid that that would be the tedious route I have to take. Thank you for confirming.